# Python kivy: How can I fix "TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters"?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a problem with my code here. I want to implement a string with data in the kv language right in my python file to add a design to the "MDTextFieldClear". I am not sure if the error has to be in kv string but after a bit of testing with the classes and the indentation of the kv string I think it could be the reason.
Here's a bit of code:

```
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.textfields import MDTextFieldClear    # KivyMD imports

class LayoutPy(FloatLayout):    # Widget class
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LayoutPy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_voc = MDTextFieldClear(helper_text="Please enter the translation", helper_text_mode="on_focus", max_text_length=12, multiline=False, color_mode="accent")
        self.add_widget(self.get_voc)

        # ... (few more widgets) ...#

Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDTextField kivymd.textfields.MDTextField
#:import MDTextFieldRound kivymd.textfields.MDTextFieldRound
#:import MDTextFieldClear kivymd.textfields.MDTextFieldClear
#:import MDTextFieldRect kivymd.textfields.MDTextFieldRect

<LayoutPy>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    FloatLayout:
        MDTextFieldClear:
            hint_text: ""
            helper_text: "Enter translation"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            max_text_length: 10
""")

class KivyGUI(App):          # Main class for build
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = ("Blue")
    title = ('Lingu Trainer')
    main_widget = None

    def build(self):
        c = LayoutPy()
        d = Factory.TextFields()
        return c


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivyGUI().run()
```

The error is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "PATH_TO_MY_PYTHON_FILE", line 106, in 
>        KivyGUI().run()
>
> File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 800, in run
>        root = self.build()
>
> File "PATH_TO_MY_PYTHON_FILE", line 100, in build
>        c = LayoutPy()
>
> File "PATH_TO_MY_PYTHON_FILE", line 54, in **init**
>        self.get_voc = MDTextFieldClear(helper_text="Please enter the translation", helper_text_mode="on_focus", max_text_length=12, multiline=False, color_mode="accent")
>
> File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 131, in **init**
>        super(BoxLayout, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in **init**
>        super(Layout, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 340, in **init**
>        super(Widget, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>
> File "kivy_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.**init**
>    TypeError: object.**init**() takes no parameters

Comment: yes , you shoud point to the line where the error comes from and msg. so far i can only guess that here super(LayoutPy, self).__init__(**kwargs) this LayoutPy. init takes no args

Comment: I added the full error message now

Comment: yes as i sayd super(something, self).init(**kwargs) calls something.init(**kwargs) but this init takes no args, probably super(Widget, self).init(**kwargs) cause trace ends there

Comment: See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on using `super` properly from `__init__`. In short, a class like `LayoutPy` has to remove any argument from `kwargs` that `FloatLayout` won't expect, because otherwise `FloatLayout` will blindly pass them on to `object`, which doesn't expect *any* keyword arguments.

Comment: Do you have a suitable solution for my code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem 1 - TypeError

```
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

### Root Cause

The error was due to the attributes, `color_mode` and/or `multiline`.

## Problem 2 - Inheritance Mismatch

In your kv file, the attribute, `orientation` is declared for class rule, `<LayoutPy>:`. This attribute is applicable to `BoxLayout`. But in your Python script, `class LayoutPy()` has an inheritance of `FloatLayout`.

## Solution

The following example use `BoxLayout` as the root.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.textfields import MDTextFieldClear


class LayoutPy(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LayoutPy, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.get_voc = MDTextFieldClear(helper_text="Please enter the translation",
                                        helper_text_mode="on_focus", max_text_length=12,
                                        hint_text="Created in py"
                                        )
        self.add_widget(self.get_voc)


Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDTextFieldClear kivymd.textfields.MDTextFieldClear

<LayoutPy>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    FloatLayout:
        MDTextFieldClear:
            hint_text: "kv: Created"
            helper_text: "Enter translation"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            max_text_length: 10

""")


class KivyGUI(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
    title = 'Lingu Trainer'

    def build(self):
        return LayoutPy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivyGUI().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Finally it's working. I tried to set the BoxLayout in the kv string so the widgets don't show up at the bottom all the time. Looking good :D